# dotnet nuget package references

Tags: .net, nuget

We have a situation in which the Microsoft Power BI nuget package references another package with a known security vulnerability. We must resolve this before going to production. We have a resolution for the vulnerability. However, I do not fully understand how this works.

The Power BI package references
Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime 2.3.21

[image]

Since we have no control over the MicrosoftPowerBi.Api package, we cannot update their reference without forking and building ourselves, which we avoid. One thing that a developer tried was to add the following package reference to the project:
Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime 2.3.24.

After adding this package reference, the nuget package for the ClientRuntime within the PowerBi.Api package now reflects that it references ClientRuntime 2.3.24.

Looking at the PowerBi.Api package references, it has ClientRuntime >= 2.3.21, so it makes sense that it works with 2.3.24, but how and why does adding a package reference for my project for ClientRuntime 2.3.24 force the PowerBi.Api package to change its internal reference in its nuget package?

[image]

This brings up another question. Let us say I have a package that references another pacakge, we will use the MediatR example (since it is in the screen shots as well). If I want my package that extends the functionality of MediatR 1.1.1, how do I ensure that my package references only specific versions of another package, much like that is done with npm packages using '^' and '~'.

To me, it seems like unchartered and untested waters to allow a force package reference version. I could understand it more if the '>=' is limited to minor and revision versions, but it seems like it would allow even the next major version.

Given the context, now the two questions.

1. How exactly is this working to force the PowerBi.Api to use ClientRuntime 2.3.24?
2. How can I limit my nuget package version references to specific versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the graph of direct and transitive dependencies is calculated; if there are differences, by default the highest wins - dependencies are "at least" normally
2. if you specify a version as `"[2.4.5]"` instead of `"2.4.5"`, it means "exactly" - if that is fine for everyone: great; if there are irreconcilable deltas, it won't build

It is a *little* more complex than that, but that's the shirt version. So by adding an explicit reference yourself at the application level with a higher version: you've increased the version that will get selected (if possible)

It is mostly assumed that hard breaks are rare and will happen at "majors", and that **you the developer** will be extra cautious at majors. It also helps to test either way, even for point releases.